# Angular cli reactive forms

Tags: angular, forms, validation, reactive

I am not able to get this validation right.I get an error Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined.

.ts file

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.addform = new FormGroup({
    firstname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, 
    Validators.minLength(4)]),
```

.html file

```
<form #addform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >
    <div class="form-group" >
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Employee Details</legend>

         <label for="fname" class="input-label"> <b>First Name </b> </label>
         <input 
            type="text" 
            class="input-text" 
            formControlName="firstname" 
            name="firstname" 
            placeholder="First Name" 
            required />
```

Comment: It was a silly mistake.I was able to fix it.

Comment: But I am having another issue. When I try to reference input values they are undefined. What am I doing wrong? just added the edited code

Answer (score 0):

Your `employee` variable is declared but not assigned any value ... which lead to an undefined variable when you call it `new FormControl(this.employee.firstname, [` here

You should at least give it a default value

Answer (score 0):

you have creating a `FormGroup` instance but its not add in html file `form` tag

```
<form [formGroup]="addform" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >       
</form>
```

just change these line work perfect

Comment: I did that. There is no error now but when I try to add the employee details its still is undefined.

Comment: @novice it works fine you can check here stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whpb8t